# AWS API Gateway - Test works, deployed API errors. Why?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup AWS Api Gateway as a reverse proxy for my actual deployed API.
My understanding is that I do this by creating a "Proxy" Resource and then specifying my http endpoint URL - as described here
[Create and Test an API with HTTP Proxy Integration through a Proxy Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html)

This works fine when I try to use the API through the "Test" function within the Resource Editor.  I can make calls to any exposed resources using GET methods and see the successful responses.

However, when I deploy the API Gateway API I can no longer access anything using the "Invoke URL" it gives me - I simply get:

```
  {
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://<myuniqueid>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api/Sector/100'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Sector'."
  }
```

If I remove the "Use HTTP Proxy integration" checkbox from the "Integration Request" I can get it working, but why doesn't it work as a proxy?

Comment: Could you give more details? (Like the raw request/response in both cases) It seems to be an issue with your endpoint returning the invalid response when using the Proxy resource type since the error message you have provided is not API gateway's. Its possible there are extra headers being sent when using proxy resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this is caused by a known issue with the HTTP proxy integration.  When you use an HTTP proxy integration, API Gateway passes all headers through to the integration endpoint, including the HOST header.  Many existing http endpoint require the use of a HOST header which matches their DNS name and in such cases, passing through the HOST header of the API Gateway can confuse the endpoint.

UPDATE: We identified a work-around for this issue.

In your integration request, explicitly add a header named "Host" and give it the value of the integration endpoint DNS name.  This will replace the Host header forwarded from the incoming client request with the Host header you specify.  This should allow your backend endpoint to function correctly.

Comment: Thanks @MikeD.  This was exactly the issue we were experiencing.